# glMapBufferOES compiles with ndk 6 but not with 7

Tags: android-ndk

I was using glMapBufferOES for those devices that supports it, like Samsung Nexus. But when upgrading to ndk 7 and building this function is not found: "was not declared in this scope".

Anyone who knows why this is? Do I need to include some other header file? I didn't see anything in the change log about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking for the answer quite some time, but just after posting I found it here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/10/topics/5271

"Since GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES was defined in glplatform in previous revision NDK, In r7, GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES was removed from glplatform. So simply add -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES=1 in cocos2dx/Android.mk, like: LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DUSE_FILE32API -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES=1"